# Recursively getting the size of a directory

Tags: ruby, directory, filesize

Is there a good gem for getting recursively calculated directory sizes? In unix, I can use `du`, but I want a library that absorbs the difference among OS.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632074/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-calculate-disk-usage-per-customer

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508692/get-available-diskspace-in-ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [sys-filesystem](https://github.com/djberg96/sys-filesystem) handles this, but you'll need to do some math to convert the available blocks into bytes (by multiplying by block-size).

Comment: This may be due the long time passed since this answer, but the mentioned gem correctly determines the block size (and also size in bytes, cf. `bytes_{used,total,free}` only on a filesystem (=mount) level and does not seem to work to determine the size of a directory.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to work:

```
Dir.glob(File.join(dir, '**', '*'))
  .map{ |f| File.size(f) }
  .inject(:+)
```

Comment: I think you're actually just getting the length of the string with `(&:size)` there. What you want instead is `{ |file| File.size(file) }`.

Comment: Or use `sum` instead of `inject(:+)` (tested on Ruby 2.6.4)

Answer (score 2):

Could something like this work for you?

```
def directory_size(path)
  path << '/' unless path.end_with?('/')

  raise RuntimeError, "#{path} is not a directory" unless File.directory?(path)

  total_size = 0
  Dir["#{path}**/*"].each do |f|
    total_size += File.size(f) if File.file?(f) && File.size?(f)
  end
  total_size
end

puts directory_size '/etc'
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution using http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html#method-c-size:

```
def directory_size(path)
  size=0
  Dir.glob(File.join(path, '**', '*')) { |file| size+=File.size(file) }
  size
end
```

Answer (score -2):

Check out the `File::Stat` class (note that it does not calculate size of directory contents, it needs to be done manually).

```
file = File::Stat.new('.')
puts file.size
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File/Stat.html#method-i-size

Comment: I assume you were downvoted because this returns the size of the directory, but not the combined size of the contents of the directory.

Answer (score -3):

Support Tools:

```
diruse /M %windir%
diruse /K /S %windir%
diruse /S %windir%
diruse /, %windir%
```

Microsoft ... system install CD

```
msiexec /i %cd:~0,2%\SUPPORT\TOOLS\SUPTOOLS.MSI /q addlocal=all
```

Sysinternals Suite Utilities:

```
du.exe -l 1 %windir%
```

Microsoft ...

[Sysinternals Suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx)

Comment: It's not clear how this solves the issue.  YOu'll need to explain